# Turning around at edges of a world

Tags: java

For a project I am supposed to write code that will have an actor have a chance to turn left or right 25% and then move 50% and then it is also supposed to avoid running out of bounds. The following code is what I have so far but I am not sure what isn't working because i am still having problem keeping the actor inbounds. Thanks

```
/**
 * Creates a new Food object.
 */
public Food()
{
    super();
}


//~ Methods ...............................................................

// ----------------------------------------------------------
/**
 * Take one step, either forward or after turning left or right.
 */
public void act()
{
    int x = Random.generator().nextInt(100);
    this.changeDirection();

    if (x < 25)
    {
        this.turn(LEFT);
    }
    else if ((25 < x) && ( x < 50))
    {
        this.turn(RIGHT);
    }
    else 
    {
        this.move();
    }
}

public void turnAround()
{
    this.turn(RIGHT);
    this.turn(RIGHT);
}

public void changeDirection()
{
    if ((this.getGridY() == this.getWorld().getHeight() ||
    this.getGridX() == this.getWorld().getWidth()))
    {
        this.turnAround();
        this.move();
    }
    else if ((this.getGridY() == 0 || this.getGridX() == 0))
    {
        this.turnAround();
        this.move();
    }
    else if ((this.getGridY() == this.getWorld().getHeight()) &&
    this.getGridX() == this.getWorld().getWidth())
    {
        this.turnAround();
        this.move();
    }
    else if ((this.getGridY() == 0) && (this.getGridX() == 0))
    {
        this.turnAround();
        this.move();
    }
}
```

Comment: If your current output does not match your desired output, and you don't know why, then it's time to start debugging. If you're not sure how to go about doing this, then please check out [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It won't solve your direct problem, but it will give you steps that you can follow that should help you solve it yourself, or even if that is not successful, then at least help you to better isolate your problem so that your question can be more focused and easier to answer.

Comment: Could you post the code for the `move` method as well?

Comment: Off by 1 error?  Should the actor turn around at `x==width-1` or `y==height-1`?